# Does hiding some content with CSS hurt SEO when "Read more" is used to show the rest?

Tags: seo, google, css

I have content that is hidden by these css

```
height: 220px;
overflow: hidden;
```

which content height is problably about 1000px, so no display: none is used on the page. I hide it because below that are users reviews and for users it is probably better solutions, but what for search engines like google ? Do they will rank my content normally as it would be visible ? thank you

PS: here is the link http://affgadgets.com/rankpay if you will click on read more you will see content, I hope that it will be ok with indexing this content